# Configured terminal window size does not create terminal windows of correct size

Tags: configuration, xfce, window-manager, xfce4-terminal

With my Xubuntu 12 with xfce I have configured a standard 80x24 window size for my terminals. But opening a window results in a smaller 79x24 window. (To me this looks like a bug - at least my former Xubuntu system did not show that behaviour -, but in case I missed something I welcome pointers.)

What can I do to get the window size I configured through my profile setting?

Additional information (in case it matters): Some additional configuration for terminal windows I have done is; activating vertical scroll bar, changing the font size to a larger font, and using a bold face font. (I think that none of that should result in a reduction of the configured dimension which is defined in units of to be displayed characters, or so I think.) And I also already looked into the configuration file `~/.config/Terminal/terminalrc` (as proposed in another SE question), but there's also just the things visible that I configured by the GUI, specifically the 80x24 setting.)

(In case it's a bug I'd also welcome hints for alternatives.)

Edit: My current workaround is to define in the GUI context menu a size of 81x24 to get the desired 80x24 terminal. (So the values in the profile preferences are obviously considered, just not correctly calculated.)

Comment: I've seen this kind of behavior when one part of the system defines the size as including window decorations (title, borders) and another part doesn't. How did you set the desired size? Are you using the xfce4-terminal or some other terminal emulator?

Comment: @Gilles; do you recall which "one part" and which "anotgher part" was that? - I set the size by the GUI context menu in the profile settings subsection. I think it's the xfce terminal; at least it's the only "terminal" that can be selected from the GUI context menu.

Comment: I don't know exactly. It's some interaction between the window manager and the application, but I don't know how initial window sizes work.